# hand-eye calibration for wheeled mobile robots

Tags: wheeled-robot, cameras, calibration

I am new to robotics and working with a wheeled mobile robot with one Kinect mounted on top of it currently.

The robot knows its position in the environment via some means.
I encounter one problem. For example there is one table, and The Kinect is
expected to guide the robot to one specific side of the table. The problem is known as  pose estimation.

By browsing the internet, I guess that hand-eye calibration may be required. However, most materials about hand-eye calibration is about robotic arms. 
I am not sure whether hand-eye calibration is needed for wheeled mobile robots.
I can't find much information about hand-eye calibration for wheeled mobile robots.
Any help are appreciated.

Comment: calibration is used to workout some unknown fixed or parameterized value/s. In hand-eye calibration, that is generally the transform between the camera and the manipulator base. What is the value you think you are missing that you suspect hand-eye calibration might help with?